# How to remove activerecord4 from gemfile.lock rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using mongoid and I want to get rid somehow from the active_record in the gemfile.lock

Can that be achieved? And How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't remove it from Gemfile.lock (it's a dependency of Rails4), but you can prevent it from being loaded by following the Mongoid installation documentation:

http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/installation.html (Getting rid of ActiveRecord section)

The relevant info:

Remove the `require "rails/all"` from config/application.rb and replace it with:

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
# require "sprockets/railtie" # Uncomment this line for Rails 3.1+
```

Comment: For the record: ActiveResource in the example above is not a part of rails 4. It was extracted to a separate gem. So do not copy it.

Comment: @Voldy Wasn't active_resource extracted way back in Rails 3.1 already? When they halted it's development?
I'd have to check if it's still being loaded in 'rails/all' but I guess the Mongoid docs are still on Rails 3.1